# Using an if statement to exclude a null date

Tags: c#

I have a DataTable that has a date field within it. I am trying to loop through it and put the value in the date field into a variable.

However when ever it is null the `oosDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0][0]);` part causes an error.

So i tried to wrap it in an if statement as shown below that checks in the fields value is null before if carries out the function. It doesnt work though and still carries out the `Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0][0])` function. Can anyone tell me why the != null isnt working?

I have checked the data that is in dt.rows[0][0] when the error occurs and it definitely appears to be null

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    { 
                        if (dt.Rows[0][0] != null )
                        {
                            oosDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0][0]);
                        }              
                    }
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing to `DbNull.Value` instead of `null`?

Comment: BTW: there is _no legitimate use_ for the `Convert` class and methods anymore (excepting the Base64 methods, ofc). Your program should _know_ in-advance if `dt.Rows[0][0]` is a (boxed) `DateTime` value or a string-representation or something else, and use an appropriate method (eg. `DateTime.ParseExact`) instead of hand-waving things away with `Convert`.

Comment: You can also use `DateTime? oosDate = row.Field<DateTime?>(0);`. The `Field`-method supports nullable types. Use `oosDate.HasValue` to check if there is a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

The value is probably `DBNull.Value`, which... isn't true null (`null`). Try instead:

```
if (!dt.Rows[0].IsNull(0))
```

An alternative would be to try `is not DBNull`, but IMO the `IsNull` method encapsulates whatever meaning of null the implementation wants to use, so you don't need to deal with the specifics.

Comment: Thats was it exactly! Thank you for your help

Comment: @Yippiekaiaii: accept the answer if answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle possible null values is to use the [`Field`-extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field?view=net-6.0):

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{ 
    DateTime? oosDateOrNull = row.Field<DateTime?>(0);
    if (oosDateOrNull.HasValue)
    {
        DateTime oosDate = oosDateOrNull.Value;
    }              
}
```

The Field-method supports nullable types. Use `oosDate.HasValue` to check if there is a `DateTime`.